# Aura Quick action not working for one of the profiles

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, component

I have a custom quick action button on the page layouts and it is working for all the profiles except one. Following error is coming
[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does that profile has access to Chatter?

Comment: Yes it has access to chatter